# Cannot set colours as values in scale_colour_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm creating a plot that depicts several data points ("region") per individual ("patient"). I'm trying to set the colours denoting the regions to a manual colour blindness-friendly palette:

```
#data sample
patient <- c("pat1", "pat1", "pat1", "pat1", "pat1", "pat1", "pat2", "pat2", "pat2", "pat2", "pat2", "pat2") %>% as.factor()
region <- c("bg", "cb", "fr", "hc", "sn", "th", "bg", "cb", "fr", "hc", "sn", "th")
abundance <- c(0.00257, 0.00172, 0.0214, 0.00594, 0.00151, 0.00955, 0.00257, 0.00172, 0.0214, 0.00594, 0.00151, 0.00955)
errormax <- c(0.00569, 0.00435, 0.0378, 0.0131, 0.00507, 0.0194, 0.00569, 0.00435, 0.0378, 0.0131, 0.00507, 0.0194)
errormin <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
mydata <- tibble(patient, region, abundance, errormax, errormin)

#palette
cbbPalette <- c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

#plot
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, mapping = aes(x = patient, y = abundance, colour = region)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = errormax, ymax = errormin), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  ylim(0,0.12)+
  xlab("Patient") + ylab("Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Brain region",
                        labels = c("basal ganglia", "cerebellum", "frontal cortex", "hippocampus", "midbrain", "thalamus"), 
                        breaks = c("bg", "cb", "fr", "hc", "sn", "th"), 
                        values = cbbPalette)
```

But the code above gives me this error:

```
Error in discrete_scale(aesthetics, "hue", hue_pal(h, c, l, h.start, direction),  : 
  unused argument (values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"))
```

Maybe `values`  is not the correct argument? Should I use something different instead?

Comment: also, I suggest a ggplot2 tutorial such as the http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `scale_colour_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydata, mapping = aes(x = patient, y = abundance, colour = region)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = errormax, ymax = errormin), width = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  ylim(0,0.12)+
  xlab("Patient") + ylab("Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Brain region",
                        labels = c("basal ganglia","cerebellum","frontal cortex",
                                   "hippocampus", "midbrain", "thalamus"), 
                        breaks = c("bg", "cb", "fr", "hc", "sn", "th"), 
                        values = cbbPalette)
```

[image]